# Consumer/Producer Exception Handling

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a circular buffer (array/first in first out), a consumer and a producer. A producer puts random numbers into the array, and a consumer takes the first number and checks if it is relative prime.

My code works, and I think it works correctly, but I want to improve it.
I am not really sure about my "void run" methods. Should I anywhere else do the exception handling? Change the "infinite-loop"? The method signatures should not be changed (they are predefined).

I would be happy about each suggestion to improve the code. (Don't care about the visibility (public,...), and static things, I've just put it together in one file.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class ConsProd {

    static class CircularBuffer {

        private BigInteger[] buffer;
        //"pointers"
        private int read;
        private int write;

        public CircularBuffer(int size) {
            this.buffer = new BigInteger[size];
            this.read = 0;
            this.write = 0;
        }

        public boolean isFull() {
            for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                if(buffer[i] == null)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                if(buffer[i] != null)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;    
        }

        public synchronized void put(BigInteger element) throws InterruptedException {
            while(isFull()){
                wait();
            }
            buffer[write] = element;
            write = (write+1)%buffer.length;
            notifyAll();
        }

        public synchronized BigInteger take() throws InterruptedException {
            while(isEmpty()){
                wait();
            }
            BigInteger temp = buffer[read];
            buffer[read] = null;
            read = (read+1)%buffer.length;
            notifyAll();
            return temp;
        }   
    }

    static class Consumer implements Runnable {

        private int id;
        private CircularBuffer buffer;

        public Consumer(int id, CircularBuffer b) {
            this.id = id;
            this.buffer = b;
        }

        private void consume(BigInteger e) {
            synchronized(e){
                System.out.println("consumer " + id + " retrieved: " + e);
                if (e.isProbablePrime(100)) {
                    System.out.println("     -----> probably prime!");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try { // TODO is this the right place to handle the exception? 
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    BigInteger e = buffer.take();
                    consume(e);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }

    }

    static class Producer implements Runnable {

        private int id;
        private CircularBuffer buffer;

        public Producer(int id, CircularBuffer b) {
            this.id = id;
            this.buffer = b;
        }

        protected BigInteger produce() {
            BigInteger x = new BigInteger(10, new Random());
            System.out.println("producer " + id + " produced:  " + x.toString());
            return x;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try { // TODO is this the right place to handle the exception? 
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    BigInteger e = produce();
                    buffer.put(e);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CircularBuffer cbuf = new CircularBuffer(4);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Consumer(1, cbuf));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Consumer(2, cbuf));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Consumer(3, cbuf));

        Thread t4 = new Thread(new Producer(1, cbuf));
        Thread t5 = new Thread(new Producer(2, cbuf));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        t4.start();
        t5.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be posted to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains **no specific problem**. Questions about *reviewing the code* may be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Should have been moved to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I thought I'd chime in.  In the future, the question seems to be better for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

> I would be happy about each suggestion to improve the code.

My first response is that you should use an `ExecutorService` as opposed to the `Consumer` threads and loop.  The producer can stay as you wrote it although I doubt having it be multi-threaded is going to help you.  Your `e.isProbablePrime()` method is prolly many orders of magnitude slower than `new BigInteger(10, new Random());`.

Because of the speed difference between the producer and consumer(s), you must create your `ExecutorService` with a limited `BlockingQueue`.  Something like the following:

```
threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                       new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100));
```

Then as your producer creates `BigInteger`s it would do a:

```
threadPool.put(new Consumer(randomBigInteger());
```

Your consumer would then not have the loop at all.  This would take care of the threads, the shared buffer, and all of the synchronization code.  You would not need to manage that.  You will need to handle recovering any results by yourself although you can also submit `Callable<?>` and use `Future<?>` to get the results.

If you can't use the `ExecutorService` stuff then your code looks pretty good although I'd use a `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead of your `CircularBuffer`.